# Display elements in special grid layout by NgIf inside NgFor in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I need to show listing items in special grid [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT1sI.jpg). The first three items are with the highest status (type=1). Next elements are with lower status (type=2 and type=3), and must be loaded in the order like in the image. But my results are displayed incorrectly, every element in one row, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKOju.png). The code of template I wrote:

```
<div id="products" class="list-group row" *ngFor="#listing of listings">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" *ngIf="listing.type==1" (click)="gotoDetail(listing)">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="{{listing.imageUrl}}" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" *ngIf="listing.type==2" (click)="gotoDetail(listing)">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="{{listing.imageUrl}}" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" *ngIf="listing.type==3" (click)="gotoDetail(listing)">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="{{listing.imageUrl}}" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" *ngIf="listing.type==3" (click)="gotoDetail(listing)">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="{{listing.imageUrl}}" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" *ngIf="listing.type==2" (click)="gotoDetail(listing)">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="{{listing.imageUrl}}" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" *ngIf="listing.type==3" (click)="gotoDetail(listing)">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="{{listing.imageUrl}}" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="moreContent">
  <center><a href="#">LOAD MORE</a></center>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Edited. Look at again, please)

Comment: Does not seem like a problem with NG2, have you concidered using One Nexus? https://github.com/esr360/One-Nexus

Comment: https://github.com/esr360/One-Nexus#responsive-grid-system

Comment: The problem is not about grid layout, but showing fetched listing items with ngFor and ngIf exactly in specified divs, dependent on listing type, like shown in image.